# QML QtQuick controls2 and Android keyboard auto-capitalization

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I am facing same issue as this post on Android: [QML TextField text erroneously capitalized on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25544185/qml-textfield-text-erronously-capitalized-on-device) ... *All letters are capitalized* for `TextField` control.

I have mixed `TextField` elements where for example when I set `echoNode` to *password*, the letters are not capitalized (no issue), while fields with normal `echoMode` get the issue, which makes me confident its under control of either Android or Qt code.
I switched to investigate from Android side and found this post [My Phone Is Capitalizing Every Word](https://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/867406-my-phone-capitalizing-every-word.html) which suggests that this problem occurs only when **auto-capitalization** is enabled on device... I tested it, turned off **auto-capitalization** on device and the issue disappeared ... 
After some investigation I found that most Android apps are build with **auto-capitalization** aware code, for example this post [Why is my Button text forced to ALL CAPS on Lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958909/why-is-my-button-text-forced-to-all-caps-on-lollipop) show solutions with Android Java code .. I wonder if this is a Qt bug or there is something to control it, for example, with `QtAndroidExtras` classes? while trying to avoid the use of Qt keyboard, I believe/hope there could be a solution from Qt side.

Comment: Does setting `font.capitalization: Font.MixedCase` help?

Comment: @Mitch, Thanks for attention, while `Font.AllLowercase` / `Font.AllUppercase` enforces the text to lower/Cap, the only thing `Font.MixedCase` does is it allows you to manually demand lower case, letter by letter .. the default and steady remains Upper!